# What mechanism creates the difference between left and right in the universe?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry

Or, more general, what mechanism creates the distinction between two opposite directions in the universe, which manifests itself in the existence of only left-handed neutrinos?
The standard model offers no explanation but gives us only a description.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50766/discussion-on-question-by-descheleschilder-what-mechanism-creates-the-difference).

Answer (score -8):

> What mechanism creates the difference between left and right in the universe?

None.

> Or, more general, what mechanism creates the distinction between two opposite directions in the universe.

None.

> which manifests itself in the existence of only left-handed neutrinos?

None. Because a right-handed neutrino is an anti-neutrino. See [hyperphysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/neutrino3.html):

[image]

Re the comments, note that parity is nothing special. Don't expect to be able to reflect the Wu experiment or a current loop in a mirror.

[image] [image]

<sup>Image1 by nagualdesign, see [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Wu_experiment.jpg), image2 courtesy of Sbyrnes321, see [Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:BIsAPseudovector.svg)</sup>

> The standard model offers no explanation but gives us only a description.

Because it's incomplete. IMHO it's much more incomplete than people think. It doesn't tell you what a photon is, or what an electron is, or what a proton is, or what a neutron is, or what a neutrino is. But I can tell you this: the electron is not a point particle. Nor are any other particles. Hence the non-local hidden variables. No particle is local. A particle can be localized by an interaction, but do not forget that the λ in E=hc/λ stands for wavelength. A photon has a wavelength. We can diffract photons. And electrons, and neutrons.

PS:IMHO you shouldn't get distracted by the Rishon model, there's no evidence for it.